# Are there unattended-upgrades security upgrades when LTS is over?

Tags: upgrade, security, release-management, custom-distributions, unattended-upgrades

Are there security upgrades when LTS is over, at least form `unattended-upgrades`?

That is, if I installed some Ubuntu and we reached some year and my LTS is over but I have an Ubuntu-[Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) server environment with sites online, should I still get any kind of security upgrades to my software from `unattended-upgrades`?

<sub>I am not aspiring to upgrade via apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y unless when I install a new server environment, thus I'd be content from the minimal upgrades by `unattended-upgrades`.</sub>

Comment: When Ubuntu 12.04LTS (2012.April release) reached EOL last year, owners had two main choices - upgrade to 14.04LTS or start paying for Canonical Support for 12.04ESM (extended security maintenance) should they keep wanting to use the 12.04 system (12.04ESM is not supported here).  As far as I know 12.04LTS to 12.04ESM was not unattended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no updates of any kind with the end of support.

Unattended-upgrades pull updates from the Ubuntu repositories, same as apt. With the end of support reached, those repositories are no longer updated, although it's still possible to use the old packages. Whatever package you install from the old repositories will be the last version available at the time it reached EoL.

In this kind of scenario, I see no point to use unattended-upgrades or apt-get update.